# Streaming mp3 file through php

Tags: php, streaming

Here is my php code to stream mp3 file through php

```
set_time_limit(0);
$dirPath = "path_of_the_directory";
$songCode = $_REQUEST['c'];
$filePath = $dirPath . "/" . $songCode . ".mp3";
$strContext=stream_context_create(
    array(
        'http'=>array(
        'method'=>'GET',
        'header'=>"Accept-language: en\r\n"
        )
    )
);
$fpOrigin=fopen($filePath, 'rb', false, $strContext);
header('content-type: application/octet-stream');
while(!feof($fpOrigin)){
  $buffer=fread($fpOrigin, 4096);
  echo $buffer;
  flush();
}
fclose($fpOrigin);
```

It's working on Mac Mini and all other PCs but not working on iPad and iPhone. Even streaming is working on all other smart phones. Your help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Why `content-type: application/octet-stream` if it's a song? Change the headers:

```
set_time_limit(0);
$dirPath = "path_of_the_directory";
$songCode = $_REQUEST['c'];
$filePath = $dirPath . "/" . $songCode . ".mp3";
$strContext=stream_context_create(
    array(
        'http'=>array(
        'method'=>'GET',
        'header'=>"Accept-language: en\r\n"
        )
    )
);
$fpOrigin=fopen($filePath, 'rb', false, $strContext);
header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="song.mp3"');
header('Pragma: no-cache');
header('Content-type: audio/mpeg');
header('Content-Length: '.filesize($filePath));
while(!feof($fpOrigin)){
  $buffer=fread($fpOrigin, 4096);
  echo $buffer;
  flush();
}
fclose($fpOrigin);
```

LE: removed `Content-Transfer-Encoding` and changed `Content-Disposition` from `attachment` to `inline`

Comment: Changed accordingly but still not working on iPhone and iPad. Code is working on PCs of all platforms and all other smart phones except iPhone and iPad. What's wrong with the code?

Comment: I've added a file name, try to add those headers too.

Comment: LE: removed `Content-Transfer-Encoding` and changed `Content-Disposition` from `attachment` to `inline`

Answer (score 3):

```
<?php
set_time_limit(0);
$dirPath = "path_of_the_directory";
$songCode = $_REQUEST['c'];
$filePath = $dirPath . "/" . $songCode . ".mp3";
$bitrate = 128;
$strContext=stream_context_create(
     array(
         'http'=>array(
         'method'=>'GET',
         'header'=>"Accept-language: en\r\n"
         )
     )
 );


 header('Content-type: audio/mpeg');
 header ("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
 header ("Pragma: no-cache");
 header ("icy-br: " . $bitrate);

 $fpOrigin=fopen($filePath, 'rb', false, $strContext);
 while(!feof($fpOrigin)){
   $buffer=fread($fpOrigin, 4096);
   echo $buffer;
   flush();
 }
 fclose($fpOrigin);
```

I know this post was from last year but someone might find this useful. This will stream the content.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old, but we just bumped into the same kind of problem with iOS.

Basically, it seems that if your app uses the native player to read the file, you NEED to implement **Accept-Ranges** and **206 Partial Content** for your file to be read.

In our case, what was happening was that the file was 4 minutes long in total. The app would play for around 1min 50 seconds and then would loop back to the start. It would not detect the total length of the file.
Even though we had set up Accept-Ranges to none, iOS was ignoring it and was still asking for parts of the file. Since we were returning the whole thing, it was "looping" back to the beginning on the next "range" read.

For the implementation of Partial Content, we used https://mobiforge.com/design-development/content-delivery-mobile-devices, Appendix A: Streaming for Apple iPhone by Thomas Thomassen

I hope this helps someone